# What I can't do with symfony 2.1 if php-intl extension has not been installed in my host?

Tags: symfony, internationalization, symfony-2.1, intl

When I check Symfony requirements in my host only throw a warning:

```
[[WARNING]] Checking that the intl extension is available: FAILED
```

I'm worried because I must deploy a fully internationalized app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use translations and everything else related with internationalization even without the `intl` extension. As far as I know the intl extension makes it possible for PHP to automatically translate, for example, month names and weekdays.

Depending on the operating system there are different ways to install the intl extension on your system. It should be bundled with PHP 5.3 (however, it is not bundled with, e.g., the PHP version that ships with OS X or MAMP), but you can install it using PECL, Homebrew, MacPorts, apt-get, etc.

- [This topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/symfony2/BktatTXX86Q) in the Symfony2 Google Group discusses the installation on Windows.
- [intl extension with MAMP](http://szemian.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/compiling-intl-extension-for-mamp/)
- [Installation intl extension with PECL and Homebrew](http://darraghenright.tumblr.com/post/22027208929/installing-intl-package-on-osx-lion)